# FosUser Menu in Sonata Admin

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

When I generate the sonata admin, it creates a Folder named "Users"

[image: SonataAdmin menu]

I want or mixed all on the same menu "Administrador" and override the label of Users

```
Administrador
     Cuentas
     Ficheros
     Secciones
     Usuarios
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just put your admin classes under the same group.

```
//src/ACME/DemoBundle/Resources/config/services.yml
parameters:
    acme.administrator.admin.groupname: administrador
services:
    acme.admin.cuenta:
      class: ACME\DemoBundle\Admin\Entity\CuentaAdmin
      tags:
        - { name: sonata.admin, manager_type: orm, group: %acme.administrator.admin.groupname%, label: Cuentas, label_catalogue: SonataAdminBundle, label_translator_strategy: sonata.admin.label.strategy.underscore }
      arguments: [null, ACME\DemoBundle\Entity\Cuenta, ACMEDemoBundle:CuentaAdmin]
    acme.admin.fichero:
      class: ACME\DemoBundle\Admin\Entity\FicheroAdmin
      tags:
        - { name: sonata.admin, manager_type: orm, group: %acme.administrator.admin.groupname%, label: Ficheros, label_catalogue: SonataAdminBundle, label_translator_strategy: sonata.admin.label.strategy.underscore }
      arguments: [null, ACME\DemoBundle\Entity\Fichero, ACMEDemoBundle:FicheroAdmin]    
      ...

//src/ACME/UserBundle/Resources/config/services.yml 
    acme.admin.user:
      class: ACME\UserBundle\Admin\Entity\UserAdmin
      tags:
        - { name: sonata.admin, manager_type: orm, group: %acme.administrator.admin.groupname%, label: Usuarios, label_catalogue: SonataAdminBundle, label_translator_strategy: sonata.admin.label.strategy.underscore }
      arguments: [null, ACME\UserBundle\Entity\User, ACMEUserBundle:UserAdmin]
      ...
```